# Render generic XML as HTML

Tags: java, html, xml, rendering

I have written a web-service (in Java) which produces as a result a (rather complex) XML document.

I'm required to return an HTML rendering of the document, if requested. Doesn't have to be fancy, displaying the XML source with some basic formatting such as correctly indenting elements would do.

How do I do this?

Comment: You need a pretty printer not an html converter. Browsers display plain text just fine.

Comment: I had a similar problem, took the default XSL of IE and modified it: http://superuser.com/questions/432354/how-could-i-embed-formatted-xml-source-in-word-documents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree, XSL would be the best approach.  If you want to turn it into something that actually looks like XML, but just inside HTML, you could use something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <!-- Evaluate Attributes -->
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <span class="attribute">
            <span class="name">
                <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
            </span>="<span class="value"><xsl:value-of select="." /></span>"
        </span>
    </xsl:template>


    <!-- Evaluate Elements -->
    <xsl:template match="*" priority="10">
        <div class="element">
            <!-- First, create the opening tag with the attributes -->
            &lt;<span class="name"><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></span><xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>&gt;
            <!-- Then, add children -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
            <!-- Finally, add the closing tag -->
            &lt;/<span class="name"><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></span>&gt;
        </div>
    </xsl:template>


    <!-- Just copy everything else (text, comments, etc.) -->
    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And throw in some CSS:

```
.element{margin-left:4em;font-size:14px;}
.element .name{color:blue;}
.attribute{margin-left:8px}
```

UPDATE:

```
<!-- Root node -->
<xsl:template match="/">
    <div class="element">
        &lt;<span class="name"><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></span><xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <!-- Grab all namespaces and declare them.  distinct-values() is XPath 2.0, however. -->
        <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(//namespace::*)">
            xmlns:<xsl:value-of select="name()" />="<xsl:value-of select="." />"
        </xsl:for-each>
        &gt;
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        &lt;/<span class="name"><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></span>&gt;
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: That's it! Only thing missing is that it swallows the namespace declarations. Any way to keep them?

Comment: Right.  xmlns attributes aren't normal attributes.  If you want to insert all the declarations in the root node, add another template the grabs all namespaces for the document and declares them up front.

Answer (score 2):

You can either equip your XML document with a generic CSS style sheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="no" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="mystyle.css" ?>
<!-- your main document -->
```

Or alternatively you can supply an XSLT stylesheet that *transforms* your document into an HTML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="no" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="transform_to_html.xsl" ?>
<!-- your main document -->
```

The former approach may be simpler and more direct, as most modern browsers display arbitrary styled XML document trees nowadays. The downside is that you need to define all the basic stylistic attributes (`display`, most notably) for *every* element type.

Comment: What would the XSL style-sheet be in this case?

Comment: @Carsten: Complicated. [Here is a skeleton example](http://pastebin.com/rWHLnK9v). Note how it creates an HTML document tree which is itself decorated with a CSS stylesheet XML processing instruction. XSLT is a fairly complex and involved language.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like something that [XLST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) may be useful for.

What kind of environment/libraries do you have available?

Comment: XSLT is a possibility, but what would the XSL be for formatting generic XML?

Comment: I think you are asking for a 'magic bullet' where none exists.  An XSLT that can transform ***any*** XML would have to be so generic as to produce horrid output.

Comment: An XLS which would print the the XML source nicely, e.g. indent elements etc. would be sufficient.

Comment: Are you saying you want the XML to appear as XML, i.e. with angle brackets visible?

Comment: Yep, nicely printed XML source code is what I'm after. Fancy stuff like colouring elements and collapsible elements would be nice, but not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you would like to transform your XML document to HTML. There are many techniques to do so including parsing the XML and generating HTML as you go. But what I recommend is using XSLT. XSLT easily allows you to transform XML to any other XML (including XHTML).

References

```
http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/
http://zvon.org/comp/m/xslt.html
```